# UI Elements in a Swift Package

Tags: ios, swift, xib, swift-package-manager, swift-framework

I've bumped into some specific problem, that I really need to be resolved:

Trying to assemble my own Swift Package with complex structure, had an idea^ that I can re-use some design elements, such as colors, fonts, images and UITableViewCell s. Course^ I've added my files to package^ but my projects does not compile because Xcode does not see my elements in scope. So, that's the problem.
[image]

There is the structure of my package^ especially, to the xib file and StandartCell.swift - they are the main ones.

[image]

The problem =(

[image]

and my package manifest

As you can see - the protocol for cell configure and the cell class are public (the main reasons in Stack questions) - but for me it does not work
[image]

Comment: I would suggest you to remove the .xib and create the UI in a swift code.
1. It will solve the issue you are facing right now.
2. it has the added benefit of getting compiled faster

Comment: @AvivFrenkel Ok, but it does not solve the problem with protocol - it will be invisible for the main target as well =(

Answer (score 0):

After 15 hours non-sleeping and just tapping out, I found out that a had wrong files structure - it should be look like that:

[image]

So, if you has some complex structure in your package - make it plain))) and all your files for package target should be  in the Package-name-folder, and all the resources process&copy processes are enable then files IN the folder.